# Append pandas datarows to excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I am having some trouble appending my data to my excel sheet. It always overwrites my previous data. I have a row of 10 columns that i need to add each time my definition is run, without overwriting the previous row.

Code up until now:

```
def sendtoxl(date, Type, e1, e1desc, e2, e2desc, e3, e3desc, e4, e4desc):
dataset = {'date': date, 'Type': Type, 'PCB1': e1, 'PCB1 info': e1desc, 'PCB2': e2, 'PCB2 info': e2desc, 'PCB3': e3,
           'PCB3 info': e3desc, 'PCB4': e4, 'PCB4 info': e4desc}
filtereddataset = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset, index=['PCB1'],
                               columns=['PCB1', 'PCB1 info', 'PCB2', 'PCB2 info', 'PCB3', 'PCB3 info', 'PCB4',
                                        'PCB4 info', 'date', 'Type'])
print(filtereddataset)

book = load_workbook('masterfile.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('masterfile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

filtereddataset.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1", index=False, header=None)

writer.save()
```

Is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [openpyxl utilities for working with dataframes](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Is there a reason python removes the shared flag on my workbook when adding rows? Is this possible to disable? I want to be able to add rows even if the workbook is opened.

Comment: No idea what you mean by shared flag.

Comment: in excel you can set the workbook to shared, so that multiple people can have it open and make changes at the same time. openpyxl removes this as soon as it writes to the file. I was wondering if there is a setting to keep this enabled.

Comment: The setting might be preserved but you cannot work on a file in openpyxl and Excel at the same time. The file is just a zipfile and zipfiles do not support inplace editing. Excel must use some kind fo protocol in this case.